# Failed to install map box in my android app with Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, maps, mapbox

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:7.0.0.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.6 > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.42.6
> > Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:7.0.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/mapbox/navigator/mapbox-navigation-native/7.0.0/mapbox-navigation-native-7.0.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/mapbox/navigator/mapbox-navigation-native/7.0.0/mapbox-navigation-native-7.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> > Could not resolve com.mapbox.navigator:mapbox-navigation-native:7.0.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/navigator/mapbox-navigation-native/7.0.0/mapbox-navigation-native-7.0.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/navigator/mapbox-navigation-native/7.0.0/mapbox-navigation-native-7.0.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**

you don't have access rights to download mapbox dependencies which need a valid token from your mapbox account.

**Solution:**

First you need to have a mapbox access token with Downloads privieleges:
Go to https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens/create and create an access token with `Downloads:READ`

[image: mapbox]

You need to specify the mapbox token on project level gradle, add your token to gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=yourMapBoxKey
```

take note that you need to enable Downloads:Read scope on your token, if not then you'll get 403: forbidden when build your project

and on your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

hope this can help solve the problem.

refs:
https://githubmemory.com/repo/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation/issues/126

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Moulaye 's answer, for me, I added the new repository URL to maven in my buildscript repositories only, and it didnot work, I was still gettting a 401 unauthorized error even with a proper token. What I did was also add authentication to my Allprojects repositories as well, like adding authentication whereever the maven repository has been mentioned. like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                username = 'mapbox'
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Twice. For anyone that might meet a similar problem for some strange reason. Make sure you generate a new download token from mapbox with a the `DOWNLOADS:READ` option checked.